# Default value for optional parameter

Tags: python, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

I'm making a function in python that takes an optional parameter `*args`. This function calls upon another function passing this optional parameter as well. However, when a certain condition applies, I want the optional parameter to have a certain default value, rather than the value passed in the function call. It is clear in the snippet of code below that simply setting a new value for `*args` is incorrect, but what is the correct method of doing this?

```
def function(arg1, arg2, *args):
    if condition:
        *args = value
    function2(*args)
```

Comment: It's not clear that setting the new value for `*args` is incorrect. Please explain.

Comment: well, it gives an error haha. I think it's bad syntax or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could identify your parameter by index in args:

```
def function(arg1, arg2, *args):
    if condition:
        args = list(args)
        if len(args) == 0:  # the second arg in args was not set
            args.append("first default")
        if len(args) == 1:
            args.append("second default")
    function2(*args)
```

But as you see - it's a little ugly. It will involve a lot of `if` statements in case you want  to use a lot of default positional arguments. Use `**kwargs` if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly `*args` is a list, so I had to assign it as `args = [value]`, instead of `*args = value`. That way it solved the problem.

Comment: It's actually a tuple, so technically it should be `args = (value,)` — but the difference won't matter most of the time.